# datatable export without cell comment

Tags: javascript, python, html, excel, datatables

I have a datatable that exports to excel and it is working however I want to add comments on hover over some of the cells.  The issue I am facing is when it is exported to excel, the hover text shoes up and I do not want it.

Here is the style sheet that controls my hover hidden comments.

```
      <style>
          .CellWithComment{
          position:relative;
        }

        .CellComment{
          display:none;
          position:absolute;
          z-index:100;
          border:1px;
          background-color:white;
          border-style:solid;
          border-width:1px;
          border-color:red;
          padding:3px;
          color:red;
          top:20px;
          left:20px;
        }

        .CellWithComment:hover span.CellComment{
          display:block;
        }
      </style>
```

Here is the script that initiates the datatable.

```
      <script>

              var instances = $('#instances').DataTable({
                  columnDefs: [{
                      orderable: false,
                      className: 'td-body-center',
                      targets: 0
                  }],
                  select: {
                      style: 'os',
                      selector: 'td:first-child'
                  },
                  dom: 'Bfrtip',
                  buttons: ['excelHtml5'],
                  order: [[1, 'asc']]
              });
      </script>
```

Here is a part of the table that shows how I am writing the comment.

```
          <tr>
                      <td><label for="running"> running</label></td>
                      <td><label for="Linux"> Linux</label></td>
                      <td class="CellWithComment"><label for="True"> True</label>
                          <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="CellWithComment"><label for="True"> True</label>
                          <span class="CellComment">Here is a comment</span>
                      </td>
          </tr>
```

"Here is a comment" is hidden and shows up when you hover on the web table, but once you export it to excel the following shows up in the cells...

```
True                           Here is a comment
```

Is there a way to prevent the comment from being exported to excel?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to get around this:
I modified the datatable creation with the following:

```
          var instances = $('#instances').DataTable({
              columnDefs: [{
                  orderable: false,
                  className: 'td-body-center',
                  targets: 0
              }],
              select: {
                  style: 'os',
                  selector: 'td:first-child'
              },
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              buttons: [
                  {
                      extend: 'excelHtml5',
                      exportOptions: {
                          format: {
                              body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                                  return data = node.innerText;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  ],
              order: [[1, 'asc']]
          });
```